# Bitbucket branch diff is only visible one-way

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-diff

I have this situation where if I compare my master branch to my dev branch on Bitbucket it doesn't show any changes but if I compare my dev branch to my master branch it shows changes.  Dev branch has the proper codebase (master is wrong) but git isn't detecting the changes to merge into Master.  What's going on?

EDIT: I was able to get master to grab the proper codebase by rebasing it onto dev using

```
git rebase -s theirs dev
```

and then force pushing master but it wiped out a bunch of my branch history.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If `master` include the "wrong" code, you can replace it with the content of `dev` with:

```
 git checkout dev
 git merge -s ours master # ignore master content, but record the merge
 git checkout master
 git merge dev            # fast-forward master HEAD to dev HEAD
```

Then a simple push is enough, no need to force.

Comment: After doing this the tip of the master branch functions properly, but there are some commits I removed in dev that reappeared in master after doing this.  In these commits I delete a file that I didn't want deleted.  If I look at Bitbucket's diff for the commit where I deleted it, it shows the file being deleted, but a few commits later it reappears in the repo without a diff showing that it was added, like it was never gone.

Comment: Simply make a new commit with the right files added or deleted, push, and move on from there.

Answer (score 0):

If compare master (**change source**) to dev (**change destination**), there is no changes. And compare dev to master, there shows changes. That means the dev branch is **newer** than master branch, the structure mainly like:

```
      A---B---C  dev
     /         
D---E  master
```

You can use `git checkout master` and `git merge dev`, it will fast-forward master branch to C, and without creating new commit id. The structure will look like:

```
D---E---A---B---C  master, dev
```

If compare master (**change destination**) to dev (**change source**), there is no changes. And compare dev to master, there shows changes. That means the master branch is **newer** than dev branch, the structure mainly like:

```
      A---B---C  master
     /         
D---E  dev
```

so you can use `git checkout master` and `git cherry-pick <latest commit id for dev branch>` to update for master branch.

Comment: git merge dev while on master branch gives me "everything is up to date".

Comment: does your git structure of master and dev branch look like as the graph, or opposite?

Comment: If it's opposite (master branch is newer than dev branch), so you should use `git checkout master` and `git cherry-pick <latest commit id on dev>` instead.